# How to avoid duplicates keys on autocomplete for headers in PAW?

Tags: paw-app

I think that this is a bug in Paw.

I written the `Authorization` key in so many request headers that appears all over the list.

[image: Header autocomplete with duplicated keys]

Comment: This is actually a bug. I have already reported it (together with some crash that is caused when deleting these entries).

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I think we have fixed this issue in the new release Paw 2.2.2, but I'm not sure. We will double check that asap and if not fixed, fix this in the next bugfix version. Thanks a lot for reporting.